# How to pass multiple params in a text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok, so i am trying to get the value from one textfield and pass it to two different methods in a viewController when the user clicks on either the "Add" button or "search" button (so if user presses search button it geoes to search method and if user clicks add button it goes to add method), so far this code does the trick but i dont like that there has to be two text fields, should i maybe use button_to's? and if so how would that look? Thx

```
  <p><%= form_tag :controller => 'projects', :action => 'search', :method => 'get' do %>

  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "search" %>
  <%= link_to_function "Clear", "$('search_field').clear()" %>
  <% end %>
  </p>

  <p><%= form_tag :controller => 'projects', :action => 'add_project_to_user' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :text, params[:text] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add" %>
  <%= link_to_function "Clear", "$('search_field').clear()" %>
  <% end %>
  </p>
```

Comment: Is the question around the text_field_tags: one in the form_tag for :action => search and one for :action => 'add_project_to+_user'?  If so, then it seems you are asking how to have multiple actions on the same form. Is that accurate?

Comment: BTW, you don't need the <p> and </p> wrapping the form_tag

Comment: yes multiple actions on same form, but i dont want multiple actions when you press search, i only want the search action for that, and i only want the add action if the user presses the add button

Comment: so i dont want to search AND add i just want a search OR add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the clarifications.  The limitation is with HTML, not Rails: A form can have only one action.  That is: one controller & action.

There are few options.  You can branch your behavior within your controller.  Have one action that handles either Search or Add, depending on which button is clicked (yes, you can have multiple buttons within the form; there is an [old railscasts (Episode 38)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form) on this. However this is rather clunky.

Another option is to use JavaScript to set the action on the form in response to the button click.

Comment: o cool, yeah I think the first option is what I am looking for, thx! If I had 15 rep points I would upvote this

Comment: When it's your own question, you're supposed to accept the answer by clicking the check mark. You can do that before getting 15 rep points.

Answer (score 0):

Have one form with two submit buttons.  Put an "onclick" event on each button.  When the button is clicked, it can use javascript to change the action of the form before the submit takes place.  Each button would obviously change the action appropriate to itself (search or add).

Comment: cool, yeah I was thinking of doing that, but not sure how to execute  the change in action, document.write()?

Comment: It would be more like $('form#the_forms_id').attr('action', 'put_the_action_here');